# What does `##*/` means in bash `${qidpath##*/}`?

Tags: bash, parameter-expansion

I try to contribute to [a Wikimedia opensource project but I don't get what `##*/` means in bash `${qidpath##*/}`](https://github.com/lingua-libre/operations/blob/master/create_datasets.sh#L47-L54). Searching on google for `##*/` is chaotic.

/tmp/datasets/raw/* contains a list of folders.

```sh
    for qidpath in  /tmp/datasets/raw/*;
    do
      qid=$(echo ${qidpath##*/} | cut -d'-' -f 1)
      if [[ $qid == Q* ]] ; then
        echo "--> Processing ${qid}..."
        /usr/bin/python3.5 /home/www/CommonsDownloadTool/commons_download_tool.py --keep --sparqlurl https://lingualibre.org/bigdata/namespace/wdq/sparql --sparql "SELECT ?file ?filename WHERE { ${query} ?record prop:P4 entity:${qid}. }" --threads 4 --directory  /tmp/datasets/raw/ --output "/tmp/datasets/${qidpath##*/}.zip" --fileformat ogg
      fi
    done
```

Answer (score 1):

This will remove all pattern beginning by `*/`: this will get a filename in your case.

Add [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) to your bookmark:

> `${parameter#word}`
>
> `${parameter##word}`
>
> The word is expanded to produce a pattern and matched according to the rules described below (see Pattern Matching). If the pattern
> matches the beginning of the expanded value of parameter, then the
> result of the expansion is the expanded value of parameter with the
> shortest matching pattern (the ‘#’ case) or the longest matching
> pattern (the ‘##’ case) deleted. If parameter is ‘@’ or ‘*’, the
> pattern removal operation is applied to each positional parameter in
> turn, and the expansion is the resultant list. If parameter is an
> array variable subscripted with ‘@’ or ‘*’, the pattern removal
> operation is applied to each member of the array in turn, and the
> expansion is the resultant list.